# Should [readdir] tag be burnitated?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-block-request

First of all, [php](/questions/tagged/php) [readdir](/questions/tagged/readdir),[perl](/questions/tagged/perl) [readdir](/questions/tagged/readdir) and [c](/questions/tagged/c) [readdir](/questions/tagged/readdir) are mixed.
Secondly, I don't think this function is so special to have its own tag and We need not tag for any function of c (or any other) language.

Besides, there is no questions with **only** this tag.

> meta tags, tags that cannot stand alone as the only tag on a question, are not allowed.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you correctly, [string](/questions/tagged/string) would need to be burninated too – it cannot stand alone on a question (on Stack Overflow), and it's a concept present in a whole bunch of languages. Same for [arrays](/questions/tagged/arrays) in a way. But these tags do help, in my view, to get a general idea of what questions are about.

The tag complements questions *about* `readdir` pretty well, whether they are C, Perl or some other language altogether. And it *is* a tricky function (in C anyway).
It makes searching for issues with that function more efficient (compared to searching for just "readdir", which will hit all questions that use that function in related code but aren't about `readdir` itself).

I don't see how this tag (or [opendir](/questions/tagged/opendir)/[closedir](/questions/tagged/closedir) for that matter) hurts.